# Query multiple tables modified inside transaction

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

I have two tables **A** and **B**. My application continuously executes transactions that consist of:

1. Insert rows in table **B**.
2. Update a row in table **A**.

(The two steps belong to the same transaction to keep table **A** and **B** mutually consistent.)

At any time **t**, I need a way to get a snapshot of the tables. More particularly, at any time **t**, I need the value of a particular row in table **B**, and I need the rows inserted in table **A** during the transaction that last updated the row of table **B**.

For example, at time **t0**, my tables have the following content:

**Table A => (rowA1)**

**Table B => (rowB11, rowB12)**

The rows **rowB11** and **rowB12** have been inserted inside the transaction that updated the row in table **A** to the state **rowA1**.

At time **t1**, the transaction is executed again, and my tables have now the following content:

**Table A => (rowA2)**

**Table B => (rowB11, rowB12, rowB21, rowB22)**

The rows **rowB21** and **rowB22** have been inserted inside the transaction that moved the row in table **A** from state **rowA1** to state **rowA2**.

Now, at any time **t**, I would like to select the row in table **A** (i.e. now it's **rowA2**) and also to select the rows that have been inserted to reach state **rowA2** (i.e. **rowB21** and **rowB22**). What I don't want, is to select the row in table **A** (i.e. **rowA2**) and to get rows **rowB31** and **rowB32** from table **B** since the state I got from table **A** doesn't match these inserted rows (that just have been inserted during a still running transaction).

I hope my question is clear enough.

I precise I'm using MySQL and I manage my transactions using Spring.

Thanks,
Mickael

---

**EDIT:**

Finally, simply using transactions with a transaction level that is at least `READ_COMMITTED` is not enough. If between the the two `SELECT`s (the one to get current state of a row in table **A** and the one to get the rows associated to this state in table **B**), one or more other transactions are executed (i.e. one or more executions of steps 1-2), the rows fetched from table **B** will not correspond to the state of the row previously fetched from table **A**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column in `B`, that allows you  to match rows in `B` with a specific status in `A`:

Time **t0**:

**Table A =>** (rowA1)
**Table B =>** (rowB11, rowA1), (rowB12, rowA1)

Time **t1**:

**Table A =>** (rowA2)
**Table B =>** (rowB11, null), (rowB12, null), (rowB21, rowA2), (rowB22, rowA2)

At **t1**, the rows in **B** you want are something like `SELECT * FROM B WHERE ref_to_A = [current_value_in_A]`.

---

*It appears that your question was related to transactions isolation, after all. So here we go:*

> Anything that happens during a transaction (unless isolation level is `READ_UNCOMMITTED`), i.e. between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`), is invisible to concurrent transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There already is a foreign key but it doesn't help since the row is always updated, and therefore the foreign key would always points to the same row.

Comment: Inserting rows into A for each state change is problematic since it the changes happen very very often.

Comment: Okay, "foreign key" was inappropriate a name, but definitely a reference from `B` to `A` that you can use to discriminate rows in `B`.

Comment: Until now, I thought that doing the two SELECTs inside a transaction with an isolation level that is at least READ_COMMITTED would be enough, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Now I think I am missing the point of your question. Regardless of the transaction, I understand your main issue is to get only rows in `B` relevant to the current status of `A`, am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry my bad, rowA1 and rowA2 are not different rows, they are the same row at two different states.

Comment: Check my proposal again. Add a column in `B`, and use it as a flag to identify rows in `B` that belong to the current status of the matching row in `A`. If it doesn't do the job, perhaps provide more examples.

Comment: Exactly and they must be the last rows inserted in table B that point to the row in table A. However, I don't want to see state of table B between the two transactional steps 1 and 2.

Comment: What do you mean by flag? Some sort of version?

Comment: If the thing is wrapped in a transaction (unless READ_UNCOMMITTED), then whatever happens between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` is invisible to concurrent transactions.

Comment: So I'm done with this problem, it was my question.... :) Thanks, for your help. Please modify your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, a "version number". If you want to keep all records in B, that is. Or else just delete old records from B :)

Comment: Using a version number will definitely solve the problem. However, using transactions seems to be much easier.

Comment: Please see my edit, using transactions solves part of the problem. However, the solution you proposed (i.e. adding a version column) solves the second part of the problem. Thanks!